# Почему не работает данный код?Ничего не помогает

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
age = int(input("Введите свой возраст : "))

if condition: (age <=12)
print("Малолетний")    
elif expression: (age >12 and age <=18)
print("Молодой")
 else:
print("Старик")
```

```
elif expression: (age >12 and age <=18)
       ^   
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 3):

у вас `if` в одном строчку,

```
if condition: (age <=12)
```

следующая строчка уж не принадлежит блоку `if`

```
print("Малолетний")
```

поэтому `elif` питон уже не понимает как обрабатывать, поскольку не видит `if` к которому он относится

```
elif expression: (age >12 and age <=18)
```

Подозреваю, что ваш код должен был быть таким:

```
age = int(input("Введите свой возраст : "))

if age <= 12:
    print("Малолетний")    
elif age > 12 and age <= 18:
    print("Молодой")
else:
    print("Старик")
```

но копипаста из какого-то учебника все погубила :)